# How to execute the Entrypoint of a Docker images at each "exec" command?

Tags: bash, shell, docker, dockerfile, entry-point

After trying to test Dockerfiles with Dockerspec, I finally had [an issue](https://github.com/zuazo/dockerspec/issues/12) I can't resolve properly.

The problem is, I think, from Docker itself ; If I understand its process, **an Entrypoint is only executed at run**, but if the container stay started and I launch an "exec" command in, it's not re-called.

I think it's the wanted behavior.

But if the Entrypoint is a "[gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu)" script which precede all my commands, it's a problem...

---

**Example**

"myImage" has this Entrypoint :
`gosu 1000:1000 "$@"`

If I launch : `docker run -it myImage id -u`

*The output is "1000".*

If I start a container : `docker run -it myImage bash`

*In this container, `id -u` outputs "1000".*

But if I start a new command in this container, it starts a new shell, and does not execute the Entrypoint, so : `docker exec CONTAINER_ID id -u`

*Output "0", because the new shell is started as "root".*

---

It there a way to execute each time the entrypoint ?
Or re-use the shell open ?

Or a better way to do that ?

Or, maybe I haven't understand anything ? ;)

Thanks !

---

**EDIT**

After reading solutions proposed here, I understand that the problem is not how Docker works but how Serverspec works with ; my goal is to directly test a command as a `docker run` argument, but Serverspec start a container and test commands with `docker exec`.

So, the best solution is to found how get the stdout of the `docker run` executed by Serverspec.

But, in my personal use-case, the best solution is maybe to not use Gosu but --user flag :)

Comment: Just `exec` with `gosu` again?

Comment: Why not `run` it each time?. Don't exec each time, just run again. The only thing is that you will create a new container each time, but I think that this is ok for testing purposes. (It is very effient anyway)

Comment: I think you're right, but this is not how Serverspec works with Docker backend ; it run a container, and after that it "exec" some commands to test in this container. But I think the solution is yours, and the problem is not Docker but how serverspec interract with :/ I'll edit my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if your goal is to run the `docker exec` with a specific user inside of the container, you can use the `--user` option.

`docker exec --user myuser container-name [... your command here]`

If you want to run `gosu` every time, you can specify that as the command with `docker exec`

`docke exec container-name gosu 1000:1000 [your actual command here]`

in my experience, the best way to encapsulate this into something easily re-usable is with a .sh script (or .cmd file in windows).

drop this into a file in your local folder... maybe `gs` for example.

```
#! /bin/sh
docker exec container-name gosu 1000:1000 "$@"
```

give it execute permissions with `chmod +x gs` and then run it with `./gs` from the local folder

Comment: Thanks, but my goal is to test my Dockerfile with Serverspec ; it builds the Dockerfile, run it and test some command ; I want to test the Entrypoint, so "id -u" must return "1000" in my example, but internally Serverspec run the container and use "exec" instead of run the command in the shell (or at run)... Just use "gosu" as a command is "cheated" and does not really test the Entrypoint :/

Comment: what you're asking for isn't possible, then. the ENTRYPOINT, by definition, only runs when the container starts