# Entering docker container with exec losing PATH environment variable

Tags: docker, environment-variables, ros

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ros:kinetic-ros-core-xenial
CMD ["bash"]
```

If I run `docker build -t ros . && docker run -it ros`, and then from within the container `echo $PATH`, I'll get:

```
/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

If I `exec` into the container (`docker exec -it festive_austin bash`) and run `echo $PATH`, I'll get:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Why are the environment variables different? How can I get a new bash process on the container with the same initial environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `ENTRYPOINT` command is only invoked on `docker run`, not on `docker exec`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723777/how-to-execute-the-entrypoint-of-a-docker-images-at-each-exec-command)

I assume that this `/ros_entrypoint.sh` script is responsible for adding stuff to `PATH`.  If so, then you could do something like this for `docker exec`:

```
docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> /ros_entrypoint.sh bash
```

Comment: It seems the environment variables aren't affected by the ros_entrypoint script. I've minimilized the Dockerfile that still reproduces the issue. I believe [this](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/blob/5399f380af0a7735405a4b6a07c6c40b867563bd/ros/kinetic/ubuntu/xenial/ros-core/Dockerfile) is the source Dockerfile, which doesn't have other `ENTRYPOINT`s

Comment: Disregard that, your command worked. I was confused because if I run exec, and then `/ros_entrypoint.sh`, once I've entered bash it doesn't work. Any idea what the difference is between the two?

Comment: @maged - If you look at [`ros_entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/blob/5399f380af0a7735405a4b6a07c6c40b867563bd/ros/kinetic/ubuntu/xenial/ros-core/ros_entrypoint.sh), you'll see that it `source`s a magical script (which presumably sets the env) and then `exec`s the arguments to the script.  Simply calling the script once you're already in Bash won't achieve anything (though I guess you could `source` it).

Answer (score 3):

`docker exec` only gets environment variables defined in Dockerfile with instruction `ENV`. With `docker exec [...] bash` you additionally get those defined somewhere for `bash`.

Add this line to your Dockerfile:

```
ENV PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

or shorter:

```
ENV PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old question but since it's where google directed me I thought I'll share solution I ended up using.

In your entrypoint script add a section similar to this:

```
cat >> ~/.bashrc << EOF
export PATH="$PATH"
export OTHER="$OTHER"
EOF
```

Once you rebuild your image you can exec into your container (notice bash is invoked in interactive mode):

```
docker run -d --rm --name container-name your_image
docker exec -it container-name /bin/bash -i
```

If you `echo $PATH` now it should be the same as what you have set in `.bashrc`